# Stripe API: Filter Paid and Unpaid Invoices

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm new to using the Stripe API and I'm running into trouble trying to get a list of unpaid and paid invoices from a particular customer.

To preface using an example: *I have a customer, they have 1 unpaid invoice and 0 paid invoices. There have been 19 failed payment attempts and none that were successful. I want to show a list of paid invoices (which there should be 0) and unpaid (which there should be 1).*

When I retrieve invoices using the following code:

```
$response = \Stripe\Invoice::all(array("customer" => $cust, "paid" => false));
```

It returns `object(Stripe\Collection)#7 (7) { ["_requestParams":protected]=> array(2) { ["customer"]=> string(18) "CUST_ID" ["paid"]=> bool(false) } ...`

It's showing one record which is what I want but I don't believe it's retrieving the unpaid invoice.

Now if I try to retrieve invoices using the following:

```
$response = \Stripe\Invoice::all(array("customer" => $cust, "paid" => true));
```

I get an entire page of objects the first line of which being: `object(Stripe\Collection)#7 (7) { ["_requestParams":protected]=> array(2) { ["customer"]=> string(18) "CUST_ID" ["paid"]=> bool(true) }...`

With the `["paid"] => bool(true)` line appearing 10 times.

I've been looking at the Stripe API documentation but it doesn't really seem to show examples of what I'm looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Are those 10 different invoices? you can check that by their ID being different, timestamps, etc. I believe stripe returns the correct states you're asking for when passing in the `paid: true / false` flag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, matov! No there is only one invoice for this customer and it's labelled unpaid on the Stripe dashboard. The fact that there are any invoices marked 'paid: true' is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I've filtered invoice using below arguments

$response = \Stripe\Invoice::all(array("customer" => $cust, "billing" => charge_automatically));

Ex.
**billing => charge_automatically**

billing:
The billing mode of the invoice to retrieve. Either **charge_automatically** or **send_invoice**.

For more details, https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_invoices

Thank you.